# WPF reading Style from ResourceDictionary to Control in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have code that looks like below:

```
ResourceDictionary res = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("Style.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
Style style = new Style();
style.Resources = (Style)res["ComboBoxTextBox"];
```

VS2008 retuns an error:

style.Resources = (**Style**)res["ComboBoxTextBox"];

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Style' to 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary'
```

How I can properly assign a style from `ResourceDictionary` to control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be as easy as

```
myControl.Style =  (Style)res["ComboBoxTextBox"];
```

Comment: Ah yes, I've just made a simple mistake :) Too hard work today :D Thx for help